# Tutorial c++ reference parameters issue

Tags: c++

I have some doubts about C++ reference parameters. I am learning from this website:

```
http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~wjk/c++Intro/RobMillerL3.html
```

First program:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int area(int length, int width);        

int main()
{
    int this_length, this_width;

    cout << "Enter the length: ";              
    cin >> this_length;
    cout << "Enter the width: ";
    cin >> this_width;
    cout << "\n";                               

    cout << "The area of a " << this_length << "x" << this_width;
    cout << " rectangle is " << area(this_length, this_width) << endl;

    return 0;
}

int area(int length, int width)   
{
    int number;
    number = length * width
    return number;
}
```

Then the author suggests that "under some circumstances, it is legitimate to require a function to modify the value of an actual parameter that it is passed".After that he introduces new function:

```
void get_dimensions(int& length, int& width)
{
    cout << "Enter the length: ";
    cin >> length;
    cout << "Enter the width: ";
    cin >> width;
    cout << "\n";
}
```

What is the main advantage when we pass values as parameters?

Answer (score 3):

**Advantages of passing by reference:**

1. It allows us to have the function change the value of the argument, which is sometimes useful.
2. Because a copy of the argument is not made, it is fast, even when used with large structs or classes.
3. We can pass by const reference to avoid unintentional changes.
4. We can return multiple values from a function.

**Disadvantages of passing by reference:**

1. Because a non-const reference can not be made to a literal or an expression, reference arguments must be normal variables.
2. It can be hard to tell whether a parameter passed by reference is meant to be input, output, or both.
3. It’s impossible to tell from the function call that the argument may change. An argument passed by value and passed by reference looks the same. We can only tell whether an argument is passed by value or reference by looking at the function declaration. This can lead to situations where the programmer does not realize a function will change the value of the argument.
4. Because references are typically implemented by C++ using pointers, and dereferencing a pointer is slower than accessing it directly, accessing values passed by reference is slower than accessing values passed by value.

**Sources**:

1. http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/
2. http://www.functionx.com/cppcli/functions/Lesson10b.htm
3. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C++_Programming/Code/Statements/Functions

Comment: Well worth upvoting if you were to mention `const&`

Answer (score 1):

There is already a good answer (imho worth accepting). However, I would like to give a more basic answer, as it seems like you encountered passing by reference for the first time:

This function:

```
void foo(int x){x +=1;}
```

can do anything with the value of the passed (by value) parameter, but it has no chance to return anything to the caller, i.e. the `x+=1` has practically no effect at all.

On the other hand, this function:

```
void bar(int& x){x +=1;}
```

gets not only the value, but it is working on the actual variable that you pass as parameter (by reference). Thus the `x+=1` has an effect also outside of the function.

Both functions in action:

```
int main(){
    int a = 1;
    foo(a);      // foo gets a copy of a and increments its value
                 // a is still 1
    bar(a);      // bar directly increments the value of a
                 // a is now 2
}
```

This is the main difference of passing a parameters by reference (bar) vs passing by value (foo). The main advantage of passing by reference is that the value of the parameter needs not to be copied. (This is whypassing by value is usually done with a const reference. Passing a const reference is like passing the value because the value cannot be changed even if actually a reference is passed.) However, for more details I refer to Rohits answer.

Answer (score 1):

`int &a` is a reference to any parameter passed to that function, You should always  think of references as Alias to a variable (it is similar to a `const` pointer).

If your reference is not `const` you are allowed to changed and therefore change the content of the original variable.

It is useful for many reason first of all it can improve performances by avoiding doing copies when passing a parameter by reference, and it is also useful if you have a function that your expecting to return multiple results for example =:

```
int f (int &a,int &b,int &c,int&d);

int main
{
    int first,second,third,result;
    result = f(first,third,result);
}
```

All your `int` variables can be change within you function.